# Should I use "not" or "without" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> My husband hasn’t spoken to me in a whole year, not/without a
>   nod or even a grunt.

Why is *not* or *without* the best option above? How do I decide in future situations?

Comment: How about *not even a nod or a grunt*?

Comment: *Without* doesn't really make sense here.  *Without* means "an absence of", or "lacking".  Try making the sentence simpler to see if that makes it clearer: *He hasn't spoken to me without a nod*?  That would mean he nods every time he speaks.

Answer (score 1):

> My husband hasn't spoken to me in a whole year, without a nod or even a grunt.

means he does speak to his wife but for a year always does so with a nod or a grunt. In this formulation, the *even* doesn't make much sense.

> My husband hasn't spoken to me in a whole year, not a nod or even a grunt.

means he has not spoke for a year and has not even nodded or grunted as a form of speech.

The second version obviously works better and is *more* correct, even though it reads a little oddly. *For* works a little better than *in* and the *even* would usually follow the *not* immediately.

Comment: As far as similar sentences in the future, this *without* could be replaced by *if he doesn't also include* and this *not* by *not so much as*. Both words have many more senses, but that's what they'll mean tacked on to the end of a sentence like this.